# Unable to see adoptopenjdk-8-hotspot in java --version

Tags: java

I have installed adoptopenjdk

```
apt search adoptopenjdk | grep installed

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

adoptopenjdk-8-hotspot/buster,now 8u242-b08-2 amd64 [installed]
```

But when I do :-

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.6+10-post-Debian-1deb10u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.6+10-post-Debian-1deb10u1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I don't see it in the above output.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried `which java`? Are the newly installed binaries in your path? Do the conflict with currently installed version?

Answer (score 0):

I was mistaken. I had to do :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and choose the `adoptopenjdk`.  Then, I had to do:

```
java -version
```

to see the newly installed java.